# Mongodb not return null values in list in ktor

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, backend, ktor, ktor-client

I'm trying to get `null` value from `collection` but in list could not get/

**My KTOR code**

```
            val teacherList = teacherTableCollection.find().toList()
        
        if (teacherList.isNotEmpty()) {
            call.respond(SuccessResponse("Teacher List", teacherList))
        } else {
            call.respond(SuccessResponse("Teacher List", "Sorry, teacher not added yet."))
        }
```

**Expected Result**

```
{
"message": "Teacher List",
"data": [
    {
        "t_id": 11,
        "t_name": "Pratik”,
        “s_id”: null
    },
    {
        "t_id": 12,
        "t_name": "Pratik”,
        “s_id”: null
    }
]}
```

**but get a response below**

```
{
"message": "Teacher List",
"data": [
    {
        "t_id": 10,
        "t_name": "Pratik",
        "s_id": 0
    },
    {
        "t_id": 11,
        "t_name": "Pratik"
    },
    {
        "t_id": 12,
        "t_name": "Pratik"
    }
]}
```

Comment: If you use the `kotlinx.serialization` library then you can try configuring the serializer with the `encodeDefaults = true` to encode all the property values with the default `null` value. https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#encoding-defaults

Comment: @AlekseiTirman thanks for comment, but when i used this `        json(
            Json {
                encodeDefaults = true
            }
        )`

api response get 500 INTERNAL Server Error currentyu im sing gson for this

Comment: hey @AlekseiTirman thanks after trouble some points finally it works